# npm installing forked respository with custom changes does not `build` the module

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, npm-install

I've been using an awesome module called [react-atv-img](https://github.com/keyanzhang/react-atv-img) for adding animations to my website. In order to add my own modifications I've [forked the repo](https://github.com/Robinnnnn/react-atv-img) and run `npm install [my-forked-url] --save` to utilize my customized tools.

For some reason, when I install my forked repo a `lib` folder doesn't get built. I'm assuming this is because the webpack script does not run. On the other hand, if I install the original repo via `npm install react-atv-img --save` there is indeed a `lib` folder inside that I can import functions from. You can see the difference here:

*npm installed my forked repo, lib doesn't exist*

[image]

*npm installed the original repo, lib exists*

[image]

As someone who's not very experienced with installing custom npm packages, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build step isn't executed on package installation. If you look at `package.json` you'll see that there is a `prepublish` script that executes (among other things) `npm run build`. So it creates and populates the `lib/` directory right before they publish to npm.

Comment: I see, that makes sense! But since I've forked it, my package.json is identical and also contains the same prebuild script. Why doesn't mine build then?

Comment: It's not building when you install your fork because you're not *publishing* it to npm. The act of *publishing* is what causes the build to automatically run (right before the module is packaged and sent to the npm registry).

Comment: Actually, I was allowed to install without publishing.

Turns out the actual problem was a bit more embarrassing - there was a linting error that failed some tests and prevented the build from being created.....